# Partial View not passing ViewModel correctly to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
namespace PGO.ViewModels.Players
{
 public class PlayerBuyinViewModel
  {
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public Buyin Buyin { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I have a view that calls this partial view and also passing in a `PlayerBuyinViewModel` object with `Player` being populated already:

```
@model PGO.ViewModels.Players.PlayerBuyinViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Buyin", "Players"))
{
    <label>@Model.Player.GetFullName()</label>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Buyin</label>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Buyin.Amount)
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2">CONFIRM BUYIN</button>
    </div>
}
```

When I call `GetFullName()` it prints out the name correctly so the `Player` is in the view but when I submit my form to the Controller `Player` in `PlayerBuyinViewModel` is `null`.

My expectation is that the same `PlayerBuyinViewModel` should be used when passed on to the controller with the `PlayerBuyinViewModel.Player` being populated as well.

`Buyin.Amount` is being populated as expected from the textbox.

Do I need to create a new `PlayerBuyinViewModel` in this partial view and repopulate it again or what might be causing this?

Comment: Why bother passing the entire `Player` when its sole purpose is the `GetFullName()`? Change your view-model to only contain `PlayerFullName` (and possibly `PlayerId` too) and you won't have to re-populate anything in the view

Comment: The `Player` object is being used in the Controller. `GetFullName()` will not be used in the View later on. But I need the `Player` object and the `Buyin` object in the controller.

Comment: Upon posting, the controller should fetch the `Player` object by the `PlayerId` passed from the view and update the relevant data (possibly `Buyin.Amount`)

Comment: Buyin.Amount is being binded because it's an input element. You don't have any input elements generated for the player, only `@Model.Player.GetFullName()` which is just for displaying.

Use playerId like haim said.